# Inserting data into relation by finding the 'id'

Tags: php, laravel

Am trying to insert data into related table, but i couldn't figure out how to fetch id of parent table to insert into relation table. There are two tables `wallet` and then `walletlogs` , walletlogs related as hasMany to wallet. Now , i need to insert data in both wallet and walletlogs, i successfully inserted data into wallet but couldnt insert into walletlogs without id. How to find the id from wallet while inserting data to it ,and use that id for inserting in walletlogs. And note that, wallet is been related to user table.

```
The relation in wallet model: 

public function wallet_logs(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Walletlog');
}

Inserting data: 

$wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $id)->increment('wallet_balance',200); // 
this is how am inserting data into wallet.
```

How to fetch id from wallet while inserting data, and using to insert data into walletlogs.

Comment: did you try something like `$log = $wallet->wallet_logs()->create([
    'some_field' => 'some value',
]);`? look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) more Inserting & Updating Related Models

Comment: But how it will create wallet_id for relation ?

Comment: The question am asking is, $wallet should give us id in order to create record in walletlog table right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From laravel docs:

> [...] The create method, which accepts an array of attributes, creates a model and inserts it into the database.

The laravel example:

```php
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```

**Update:**

For your question:

```php
$wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $id)->first()->increment('wallet_balance',200);

//Since `->increments()` does not return a query builder instance, you can not chain your calls like `->increments->wallet_logs()`, and need to get the wallet again:
Wallet::where('user_id', $id)
    ->first()
    ->wallet_logs()->create([
        'field_name' => 'value'
    ]);
```

**Update 2**

To avoid the two queries of the first example, you can do something like this:

```php
$wallet = Wallet::where('user_id', $id)->first();
$wallet->increment(200);
$wallet->wallet_logs()->create([
    'field_name' => 'value'
]);
```

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is the error am getting `Call to a member function wallet_logs() on integer`

Comment: I forgot the `->first()`. Try it again

Comment: Now it gives `Call to a member function wallet_logs() on integer`

Comment: Can you `dd(Wallet::where('user_id', $id)->first())` and post the result? (A screenshot on imgur would be nice)

Comment: i've updated my answer. I forgot that `->increments()` does not return a query builder instance, so you can not chain your calls like `->increments()->wallet_logs()`.

Comment: It works, is this good approach ? Having two queries ?  Or any thing you can suggest ?

Comment: Maybe query the wallet first, and then increment the wallet ballance and create the log should work fine for you.

Comment: Perfect Thanks !

Comment: Glad that i can help you!

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try running a select query to get the id from the related table, post it into a variable and do this instead of fetching